# How can an App freeze Android OS

Tags: android, freeze

I am developing an Android app that is causing the OS to Freeze.

My question is rather simple but after lengthy searches I have come no closer to an answer.

The question is, how can an app which is sandboxed, cause the entire Android OS (4.0.4, 4.1.1, 4.1.2) to freeze?

Specifically, the entire OS freezes.  No logcat, no adb, nothing!  It is as frozen as an OS can get.  The device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.  The app uses the `UsbManager` and the library from the [usb-serial-for-android project](https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/).  While the library may use the NDK, my app does not.  Essentially, the app communicates serially with a propriety board, receiving data and sending serial commands.  This is done on a worker thread that is disposed of in this manner:

```
try {

        thread.interrupt();
        thread.join();          
        while(thread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED){
              // wait until thread finishes
        }

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It all works fine, that is until the freeze occurs - when I disconnect the usb cable or instruct the library object to disconnect.  Either way, the entire OS gets unstable and will freeze immediately or upon connecting the usb again (board or computer).  I have posted this freeze issue to the usb-serial-for-android project but have not received any comments yet.  I believe I am following the proper protocols when disengaging the usb.

I understand many things can go wrong - my app can crash et. al.  But again how does a sandboxed app crash the OS - it does not seem to be very sandboxed if it can do that.

**UPDATE**

I have after much experimentation found that by removing the `thread.interrupt();` line that it works without crashing the app or freezing the OS. It still freezes the OS if the USB is unplugged without first dismounting it.

I still desire to understand how a sandboxed app can freeze the entire OS though.  There are comments here that elude to an answer, but are not an answer alone.

Comment: freeze, as in you can't even go to home using the home button? are you using an emulator or a real device? if you used a device, what is that device? if it is connected to the computer, what did the logcat say? what happens that can cause the freeze?

Comment: Many things. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I would be looking for a tight loop with unsatisfied termination conditions, or behavior such as recursively restarting itself. Since you are *(of course)* using source control, rollback to the last known working version and step forward to find what changes cause the problem.

Comment: You also don't describe what the app does. Are you doing anything with low level graphics or sound or something in C (NDK) which may explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: That Apps can freeze Android is an annoying fact. Mostly happen because an App does too much in the UI Thread, blocking Androids reaction on users input. But your case seems to go further, also blocking logcat and adb. Especially the two are based on Linux services, so your app shouldn't be able to do that. For us, to be able to help, you must investigate a bit more. My guess: Native calls in the serial USB library. This lib must do some real time handling of incoming data -and might forget to give the rest of the world a chance to be handled.

Comment: Is it possible the usb serial library is still reading/writing to port after USB DETACH has occurred? Did your code stop SerialInputOutputManager thread after USB DETACH occur?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code sample above located?

It should be be on a UI thread, potentially blocking user interaction.

Are you also getting [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) messages before the freeze?

```
    thread.join();
```

will block indefinitely. See [Thread.join() documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29).

Also, the following looks like a busy loop to me.

What are you doing at the comment? If nothing, then the loop will spin like crazy (think `while (true) { }`).

```
    while(thread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED){
          // wait until thread finishes
    }
```

Comment: No ANR just the OS freezing.  Worker threads are used to prevent UI blocking.  As stated in the post, it all works fine until the usb is disconnected.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your mention of Worker. Looks like [destroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy()) is deprecated. I'd comment it out. Also join can block, I would suggest to try join(milli, nano); Also put in a final } catch (Exception e) { as a catch all and comment out the whole while loop.

Comment: I have seen many posts recommending the thread termination process I am using - you cannot kill a thread directly (you can but it is not advised), you have to tell it you no longer need it (`with join`) and wait - thus the loop.  I have tested this w/o the usb library in a proof-of-concept scenario to be very successful.  Not waiting in the loop until the thread finishes is not recommended because destroying the object that creates it causes the app to get very unstable and goofy.